# Need help on an algorithm (stack overflow)

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, recursion, segmentation-fault

This is a problem a friend of mine gave me as a challenge. I've managed to come up with a recursive algorithm that works fine for small inputs, however I get segmentation faults for large values. I suppose that's because of a stack overflow. I use the C language for solving the problem.

You are given an array of n numbers. Find and print the maximum length of the subset such that for any two numbers form that subset, the sum of the numbers is not divisible by k.

Input contains on the first line 2 numbers n and k, on the next line there are n numbers a[i] such that:

```
1 <= n <= 10^5
0 <= a[i] <= 10^9
1 <= k <= 100

# Example input:
4 3
1 7 4 2

# Output:
3
```

Explanation: `(1 7 4) 1 + 7 = 8; 1 + 4 = 5; 7 + 4 = 11;` all of them non-divisible by 3.

My solution is based on the following idea: For all numbers in the array check the sum with the others if it is divisible by k. If we find a match then create 2 arrays, one excluding the first term of the sum and one excluding the second one, this way we exclude such pairs from our subsets. Then do the same thing we did to the first array to both of them. If we have checked all the elements from the the array then set the solution to the length of the array and continue applying the "solver" to only the arrays that have a length greater than the solution already found. This algorithm works well for n < 47 , more than that and it gives me a seg fault. I would like to see any solution that solves the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int n, k;

int * deleteElement(int * a, int n, int j){
    int *c = (int*) malloc((n-1) * sizeof(int));
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(i == j) continue;
        c[k] = a[i];
        k++;
    }
    return c;
}

int sol = 0;

void solver(int *a, int n, int *sol){
    int *b, *c;
    if(n <= *sol) return;
    for(int i = 0; i <  n-1; i++){
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++){
             if((a[i] + a[j]) % k == 0){
                  c = deleteElement(a, n, i);
                  b = deleteElement(a, n, j);
                  solver(c, n-1, sol);
                  solver(b, n-1, sol);
                  return; 
             }
         }
     }
     *sol = n;
}

int main(){
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%d", &k);
    int a[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    solver(a, n, &sol);
    printf("%d\n", sol);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a non-recursive implementation of your same algorithm? Or are you open to completely different algorithms that solve the same problem in a more-efficient way?

Comment: I mentioned that I would like to see any solution, I am just curious how would I be able to transform this into an iterative algorithm. This seems to be an important skill for me to have in general when dealing with segmentation faults due to stack overflow.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I now see that that's in your last sentence before the code dump ("I would like to see any solution, however I would prefer to see how can I transform this algorithm into an iterative one"). The problem is that those are two very different questions.

Comment: Ok, I have tried to limit it to a single question, please notify me if further edits are necessary.

Comment: A bit OT: is `subset` contiguous or part of the set, in other words, for input `1 7 4 2`, is `7 2` a subset or not?

Comment: I'd use an intermediate representation, e.g. like this: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1Dg0EUc1gfv88Q_ZI4zv5uITfcssUS0zeW2ZSPm0vlyY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes, 7 2 is a subset in this case. The problem doesn't actually specify what does it mean by subset so I'm not sure whether I should give my own definition of a subset, however I am pretty sure this means part of the original set, of any length, even length 0. This means you can create a subset only by excluding 0 or more elements from the original set, not by any other means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use iteration to get rid of one of your two recursive calls, but that wouldn't help with stack space, since they have the same depth -- one call is as bad as 2.

It's easy enough to write a completely iterative algorithm that actually tests all the valid sets, but that's still an exponential time algorithm.  In any case that this would save you from a stack overflow, it would take *way* too long to run.  Since that algorithm would also suck, I don't want to write it.

A reasonable linear-time way to solve this problem is:

1. Calculate a map MODCOUNTS where MODCOUNTS[m] = the number of elements x such that x%k == m
2. Since any valid subset can only have one element divisible by k, if MODCOUNTS[0] > 1, then set MODCOUNTS[0]=1
3. Similarly, if k is even, and MODCOUNTS[k/2] > 1, then set MODCOUNTS[k/2]=1
4. Now, add up all the values in MODCOUNTS, but leave out a value MODCOUNTS[i] if:

   - i > 0, i*2 < k, AND MODCOUNTS[i] < MODCOUNTS[k-i]; OR
   - i*2 > k AND MODCOUNTS[i] <= MODCOUNTS[k-i]

rule 4 reflects that fact that a valid subset cannot include any elements x and y such that (x+y)%k = 0, for the cases that we didn't take care of in rules 2 and 3.  The biggest valid subset includes all the elements from in MODCOUNTS[i], or all the elements in MODCOUNTS[k-i], but not elements from both.

If you use sparse data structure like a hash table to implement MODCOUNTS, then the whole thing takes O(N) time.

Comment: Thank , you very much, great solution, initially didn't work for all the cases because I made the map n in length, when it should have been k, now it passed all the cases. Can you recommend me a way of getting better at finding efficient algorithms such as yours?

Comment: It takes intuition that comes from practice, experience, and study, I'm afraid.  The first part is knowing when to stop looking for better solutions, by comparing how long your algorithm takes (easy) with how long an algorithm for your problem *should* take (hard).  Then you have to be familiar with a lot of clever algorithms and their tricks.